# The vertex of the parabola is the point (a,b) and latus rectum is of length l. If the axis of the parabola is along the positive direction of y-axis

Tags: conic-sections

Problem :

The vertex of the parabola is the point (a,b) and latus rectum is of length l. If the axis of the parabola is along the positive direction of y-axis, then its equation is

(a)  $(x+a)^2= \frac{l}{2}(2y-2b)$

(b)  $(x-a)^2 =\frac{l}{2}(2y-2b)$

(c)  $(x+a)^2 =\frac{l}{4} (2y-2b)$

(d) $(x-a)^2 = \frac{l}{8}(2y-2b)$

My working :

Since the axis of parabola is along y axis therefore the equation of parabola will be of the type :

$x^2 = 4ay$

Now since length of latus rectum is 4a ( where a is the distance of focus from vertex) here it is $ 4a =l \Rightarrow a = \frac{l}{4}$

Now since vertex of parabola is shifted from origin (0,0) to (a,b) therefore the equation will become :

$(x-a)^2 = l (y-b) \Rightarrow (x-a)^2 = \frac{l}{2}(2y-2b)$ So answer is option b. but this is wrong answer option d is correct please guide on this.. thanks.

Comment: I got the same answer as you. I think `b` is correct.